# Fluid mountains when using standard assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, terrain

I am just starting to use the terrain object in unity and I created some terrain around me but when I use the FPS character from standard assets and move around the mountains seem to make a "wave" effect on the horizon. I have attached a video of this. I don't know how else to explain it.

Here is the video link to what is happening:

https://youtu.be/FeJWWoJpMDQ